# Construct a triangle given the length of one side, the angle opposite that side and the difference of the remaining sides.

Tags: geometry

Given is length $c$, the angle $\gamma$ and $a - b$. I need to construct a triangle with those properties using only elementary geometry (without trigonometry). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw the segment $AB=c$ and its perpendicular bisector $p$. Construct the point $O$ at the bisector such that $\angle AOD=\gamma$. Draw a circle $c_1$ with center at $O$ and radius $OA$. Let the intersection of the circle with the perpendicular bisector be $D$. The points $O$ and $D$ lie in the different half-planes separated by the line $AB$ if the angle $\gamma$ is acute. They lie in the same half-plane if the angle is obtuse.

Now draw another two circles: $c_2$ centered at $A$ with radius $b-a$ (assuming $b>a$, otherwise the circle centered at the point $B $ shall be used), and $c_3$ centered at $D$ with the radius $DA$. Let the intersection of these two circles be $E$ (the points $D $ and $E $ lie in the different half-planes separated by the line $AB $). Draw the line $AE$ till the intersection with the circle $c_1$. The point of the intersection $C$ is the third vertex of the triangle in question (one can easily verify that the triangle $BCE$ is isosceles).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I assume you meant $abs(b - a)$, since $a > b$?

Comment: @zaq In my solution I assumed $b>a$. In the case $a>b$ you should interchange the labels for $A$ and $B$.